# Codeigniter ORA-00001: unique constraint

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, ora-00001

This error: Message: oci_execute (): ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.NAME CONSTRAINT) violated

I wonder if I do not how to handle the error more simply, more generic.

Because otherwise I will have to work on each function of the models to check the data before adding, for no duplications and not give the error noted above.

Does anyone know a simple way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't show your table definition, or what the constraint is, but if you are trying to insert rows with duplicate values that have a constraint, then there is probably something wrong with your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hint that can be specified that will allow the statement to succeed without inserting the duplicated data. It can be useful for replication or bulk data loading where the job may attempt to insert the same data multiple times. I wouldn't recommend it as part of a user application.

"The [IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF30052) hint applies only to single-table INSERT operations. It is not supported for UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, or multitable insert operations. IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX causes the statement to ignore a unique key violation for a specified set of columns or for a specified index. When a unique key violation is encountered, a row-level rollback occurs and execution resumes with the next input row."

Comment: Sorry, let me explain.

The database does not allow insertion of duplicate data in some cases. I know I could handle it when making the insert, verify that the record in question is not registered already.

The problem is that this system is ready, and I will have lots and lots of screens to change.

What I wanted was to know if there's no way I handle this error in order to obtain the return of the same and inform the user a message. So I would not change a number of methods in various models.

Thank you very much.